# Is it possible to execute a test that takes its data from TFS without any table parameters?

Tags: c#, testing, tfs, mstest

I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 3 and TFS 2015 update 3. Below is an example of a test case (psuedocode).

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource(PROJECTNAME, TFSURL, TESTCASENUMBER, DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
public void Test()
{
   OpenUrl("someurl");
   Assert.IsTrue(Url is displayed);
}
```

The *TESTCASENUMBER* is linked to a test case on TFS and does not contain any parameters, so the table is empty. Since the table is empty the test will skip with the message 'Table *TESTCASENUMBER* is empty'.

Currently the workaround I have been using is to add a dummy parameter to the test case so the test will run. Is there a better workaround than this?

Comment: I could reproduce your scenario. If the parameter is empty, the test will skip. Since you don't need to test the parameter, why do you connect TestCase DataSource? Could you provide code of OpenUrl()?

Comment: The code OpenUrl() is just an example. The reason to connect to the DataSource is so our automated tool can link this test method to a test case within TFS. In short, the tool will take the TESTCASENUMBER from the datasource, search for that test case on TFS and associate the test method to that test case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use DataSource, you can simply associate the test method in a TestCase, check the screenshot below:

[image]

In this way, when the automated tool run this TestCase, the test method is linked. You can check article below for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: We use to manually associate test cases to the test method as per the screenshot supplied. But this becomes tedious for a large number of test cases, so we created a separate automation tool that will link the test cases for us. The tool requires the test case number within the DataSource attribute as a reference on what test case to link the current test method to.

Comment: @Brian, Just as we tested, if the parameter is empty, the test will skip. We can't modify this. If you insist on using DataSource, the only way is to add a dummy parameter to the test case as you did.